# Feature Request: Question Variants

Tags: feature-request

How often have all y'all come across a question that has already been answered, but the OP points out that the solutions to the original question don't really answer some variant of the original question that they need a solution for? Would it be helpful to gather all these related questions under one roof (e.g. one page)?

I'm not sure what this feature would look like exactly, but I'm thinking, if you come across a question that's really close to yours, but you have a few nuances that aren't accounted for and require a different solution, perhaps you could click an "Add Variant" button. Variant questions and their solutions would be viewable from the same page as the original question.

Or, perhaps, just listing duplicate questions on the original unique question page would be sufficient. That way, people can see other variants that might be helpful, or, when they add their own variant question (as a new, normal question), it will be visible from the original question.

Comment: That sounds like introducing huge complexity to a system that currently is very straightforward: you have a question, and answers, period. The common way to go in a situation like this is starting a new question and making it very clear that it's similar to, but not identical to the other.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. I think a lot of SO users find it complex enough (the way things are now) to decide if their question qualifies as being unique enough. I don't really see how variant questions are more complex than duplicate questions--it's the same general concept, just organized in a more helpful way, so that you can go from parent-to-child as well as the current child-to-parent navigation.

Comment: You mean like the "linked" list in the side bar?

Comment: The question is less how useful this would be for the OP and more how useful would it be to future visitors, and I'm thinking, not very. This site thrives on focused well constructed questions, and so if another issue arises, diffusing the question's focus reduces its future usefulness. The solution is to ask a new question, one that perhaps links to the first if need be, but one that asks the new focused problem in its own light.

Comment: @Trevor "users find it complex ... to decide if their question qualifies as being unique enough" - I think it is quite strange observation. I'm completely sure users strongly believe they questions are always unique and don't need to decide anything there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually, I don't disagree with the OP there. I'm sure for someone new to the profession it can be *incredibly* hard to decide whether their problem is unique enough because they can't judge whether the factors that seem to make their problem unique are trivial or not. Don't think a "variations" feature is the solution for that though.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm familiar with Related questions, how do you add questions to the "linked" list in the side bar?

Comment: @Trevor any time a link to a question or answer is posted in a question, answer, or comment on another post, it is added to the linked section.

Comment: Well, I suppose that provides the necessary functionality, then; However, it would be nice if it were more obvious. I've been on this site for 7 years (probably much longer than that feature has been around) and I've never noticed it. I doubt newer users are generally aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we really need that.

Personally, if I'm asking a question that's very similar to one that's already been asked, I link to it as a related question and explain why it's different. If I can't convincingly explain why my question's different than the previous one, clearly it's a duplicate.

I'm not sure that it's strictly accurate to say that closely related (but non-duplicate) questions are necessarily "variants" on each other *per se*. There are plenty of cases where you might want to know about different aspects of a same question, applications of a general principle to different circumstances, etc.

A good example is an issue that came up on Literature SE recently. The three related questions are listed below, and you can find the Meta post discussing whether the latter two should be marked as duplicates of the first one [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/duplicate-questions-about-authorial-intent).

- [How much weight is given to authors' intentions in literary analysis?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-much-weight-is-given-to-authors-intentions-in-literary-analysis?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [The author of a literary work disagrees with critics about meaning—who's right?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/the-author-of-a-literary-work-disagrees-with-critics-about-meaning-whos-right?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How much weight should we give authors' declarations of their intent after the fact?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/how-much-weight-should-we-give-authors-declarations-of-their-intent-after-the-f)

The second two were looking at edge cases that weren't fully addressed in the first one (and couldn't really have been without making the question too broad). The solution was for the OPs (one of which was me) of the second two questions to edit to clarify that.

Comment: "There are plenty of cases where you might want to know about different aspects of a same question, applications of a general principle to different circumstances, etc." -- Exactly. Hence being able to see variant questions (not related because they have similar tags and share a few common words in the title, mind you, but questions that actually address different aspects of the same general principle).